# Moving a row that contains certain text up to the last row in an array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've searched here and tried modifying a few scripts but haven't had any luck.

In my sheet, there is a query bringing in production data. Below that data, I have a floating Grand Totals row that sums the sku count, total quantities and costs of the data above. We typically drag this row up after all of the production line items are confirmed, below the last line.

I would like to search for a row in Column A that contains the text "Grand Totals" and move that row, its formulas and formatting, up below the last row in the production data. This should all be done to the active sheet, From Row A6-A499. I do not want to get the range from a named sheet as the sheet names are dynamic with the week number of the production plan in them.

Been using SO for years, but this is my first post. Please excuse me if this is a repeat. I have searched many threads and haven't been able to complete this script.

Here is the script I hacked together - I feel like the if statement is missing something.. but its likely more than that.

If the direction and script below is not enough I can make a shared sheet with discreet data, but I'm hoping i've explained my needs well enough.

I added a UI menu item to run it thinking that I would need to be on the 'active sheet' when it was ran, in order to also circumvent needing to define a certain sheet name. I could see it being useful on all sheets in the workbook as well, triggered on edit or something. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("⚙️ Admin Settings")
    .addItem("Move GT", "MoveGT")
    .addToUi();
}

function MoveGT() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var r = s.getRange("A6:A499");

  if(r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getValue() == "Grand Total") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Comment: the `r.getColumn()` only returns the position of the first column in the range, `r.getValue()` only returns the value of the top-left cell in the range.

for your case I think you should use `r = s.getDataRange()` to get the range of data
the iterate over the first column of the range to find the row of 'grand total', or just `r.getLastRow()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to search a value of "Grand Total" from column "A".
- You want to move the searched rows to the last row of the same sheet while keeping the cell format and the formula.
- You want to move the searched rows to the last non-blank row in the A6:L499 range.

In your showing script, when the cell "A6" has a value of "Grand Total", I think that your script works. But, I'm worried that your script cannot be used when "Grand Total" is put in the cells except for "A6". I guessed that this might be your current issue. If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function MoveGT() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var r = s.getRange("A6:A499");

  // I modified the below script.
  var lastCol = s.getLastColumn();
  var ranges = r.createTextFinder("Grand Total").matchEntireCell(true).findAll().map(e => e.offset(0, 0, 1, lastCol));
  if (ranges.length == 0) return;
  var lastRow = r.getDisplayValues().findIndex(([a]) => a == "") + r.getRow();
  ranges.forEach((e, i) => e.moveTo(s.getRange(lastRow + i, 1)));
  ranges.reverse().forEach(e => s.deleteRow(e.getRow()));
}
```

- When this script is run, a value of "Grand Total" is searched from column "A". And, the searched rows are moved to the last row of the same sheet.
- I think that in this case, the following modified script might be able to be used.

  ```js
  function MoveGT() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var r = s.getRange("A6:A499");

    // I modified the below script.
    var offset = r.getRow();
    var values = r.getDisplayValues();
    var rows = values.reduce((ar, [a], i) => {
      if (a == "Grand Total") {
        ar.push(i + offset);
      }
      return ar;
    }, []);
    var len = rows.length;
    if (len == 0) return;
    var lastRow = values.findIndex(([a]) => a == "") + offset;
    var lastCol = s.getLastColumn();
    rows.forEach((e, i) => s.getRange(e, 1, 1, lastCol).moveTo(s.getRange(lastRow + i, 1)));
    rows.reverse().forEach(e => s.deleteRow(e));
  }
  ```

#### References:

- [createTextFinder(findText) of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createtextfinderfindtext)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: So very close! Your script pushes it to the last row on the sheet. 

Apologies, I forgot to mention that I require when moving the row, it must searching for the last non-blank row in the A6:L499 range. This is the window data comes in without any formulas inside that range. Columns M-Q have formulas that are cascaded to the last row in the sheet which is likely why your script chose that last row. 

At A500:L600, I have a hidden query used in another script. 

While I want to move the whole 'Grand Total' row, I need to determine the last row with data in A6:L499 and move it below that.

Comment: That did it. Thank you so much for the help Tanaike! This will greatly help our new process.

Comment: @workflowz Thank you for replying and testing it again. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.